# How to get authorization_code from Gmail API in angular 5 app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-api, gmail-api

I am working in an Angular app, I want to add Gmail in this Angular app.

I have followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@mcflyDev/angular-2-or-4-import-google-contacts-d0ffb13d8626

everything is working fine and I am getting the success response with `access_token` but I am not getting `authorization_code`.

How can I get `authorization_code`?

Here is my configuration:

```
     this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'bla-bla-bla-2.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        access_type: 'offline',
        response_type: 'code',
        auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
        prompt: 'select_account',
        include_granted_scopes: true,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      });
```

Also, I am also not getting `refresh_token`, as you can see I have already set `access_type: 'offline'`.

[image]

I am getting this response as shown in the above image.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Arpit Meena did you find the answer? A have the same problem.

Comment: @pelcomppl, are you making `POST` Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Earlier I was making a `POST` Ajax call but that was not required.

We just need to do a small setup in 2 steps:

**Step 1. Prepare a URL:**

The URL should look like this:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=:your_redirect_url&response_type=code&client_id=:your_client_id&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline
```

You can paste this URL in your browser and hit enter to check it is working.

**Step 2. Create an anchor tag in HTML:**

```
<a href="giveAboveURLHere">Connect With Gmail</a>
```

Congratulations!!! You have done.

Whenever user will click on this link, Google will ask for permission for the provided scope and if the access is granted by the end user then Google will redirect to the given `redirect_url` with the `authorization_code` in the query param.

Then on the server side, you will need to make another `API` call with this `authorization_code` then Google will provide `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

Thanks, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

@Arpit Meena
I found another solution:

On button "Connect With Gmail" click I run `this.auth2.grantOfflineAccess()`.

It fires google account choose popup and immediately after that popup to grant privileges to scopes. It returns `authorization_code` which I can use to get refresh_token and access_token in my API (`$gClient->authenticate($code);`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the one i found best to get auth code by use of js client library.
rest on g-site only http/rest method is mentioned.

```
function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
              apiKey: API_KEY,
              clientId: CLIENT_ID,
              discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
              scope: SCOPES,
              access_type:'offline',
              include_granted_scopes: true
            }).then(function () {
         
              offinebutton.onclick = offlinefunction;
              
            }, function(error) {
              appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            });
          }

    function offlinefunction() {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess().then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.code)
            });
          }
```